# How to use swagger with dropwizard .0.7.0

Tags: swagger, dropwizard

I have the latest dropwizard setup.  Now I have created a simple API and I am trying to add Swagger on top.  There is a Swagger implementation for dropwizard but the sample code is against Yammer dropwizard 0.6.2 which requires addProvider and addResource. The io.dropwizard environment doesn't seem to have this function. Can you please let me know how I can do this under io.dropwizard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Dropwizard 0.7.0 I configure swagger like this:

```java
void configureSwagger(Environment environment) {
  environment.jersey().register(new ApiListingResourceJSON());
  environment.jersey().register(new ApiDeclarationProvider());
  environment.jersey().register(new ResourceListingProvider());
  ScannerFactory.setScanner(new DefaultJaxrsScanner());
  ClassReaders.setReader(new DefaultJaxrsApiReader());
  SwaggerConfig config = ConfigFactory.config();
  config.setApiVersion(API_VERSION);
  config.setBasePath(".." + environment.getApplicationContext().getContextPath());
}
```

**EDIT**

To run [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) with Dropwizard clone the repo and copy the `dist` directory into `src/main/resources/swagger/` (customizing as necessary). Then add the asset bundle like this:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<ApplicationConfiguration> bootstrap) {
  bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/swagger/", "/docs", "index.html"));
}
```

Comment: So this gets me the JSON, which is great, but how do I get that Rich swagger UI?  Theres something obvious I'm missing here.  Is this the "static asses" discussion from the Drop Wizard docs?

Comment: @nullpointer See my answer below for generating swagger.json in 1.0.0

Answer (score 2):

There are some changes for Swagger spec 2.0 that you can see here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/develop_2.0/samples/java-dropwizard

Namely the configuration is slightly different:

```
  @Override
  public void run(SwaggerSampleConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
    environment.jersey().register(new ApiListingResource());

    // specific to the sample
    environment.jersey().register(new PetResource());
    environment.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();

    // api specific configuration
    config.setTitle("Swagger sample app");
    config.setVersion("1.0.0");
    config.setResourcePackage("com.wordnik.swagger.sample");
    config.setScan(true);
  }
```

Comment: where can i import beanconfig from ?

Comment: Look under `io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig`

Answer (score 1):

Dropwizard 1.0.2, Swagger 1.5.0. Call this from your application's `run()`.

```
private void configureSwagger(Environment environment) {
    BeanConfig magicBean = new BeanConfig();
    magicBean.setVersion("0.1");
    magicBean.setTitle("title");
    magicBean.setBasePath("/api");
    magicBean.setResourcePackage("com.me.resources");
    magicBean.setScan(true);
    environment.jersey().register(new ApiListingResourceJSON());
    environment.jersey().register(new SwaggerSerializers());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @fehguy messaged above, I would like to add on how to actually get the base path in dropwizard as well (atleast with 0.8) because apparently you will not be able to get basePath from the yml like this :

```
config.setBasePath(".." + environment.getApplicationContext().getContextPath());
```

You will have to do do something like this:

```
DefaultServerFactory defaultServerFactory = (DefaultServerFactory) serverConfiguration.getServerFactory();
String basePath = defaultServerFactory.getApplicationContextPath();
```

Refer to the github issue [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/957#issuecomment-87377424) which took me DAYS to figure out. Hope this helps others