# What Maven Dependencies to use Swagger with DropWizard 0.7.0

Tags: java, rest, maven, swagger, dropwizard

I have an existing dropwizard 0.7.0 service which I would like to document using Swagger.  I am using the followind dependency for swagger from https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/JavaDropwizard-Quickstart

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However when I add that dependency I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaTypeModifier.modifyType(GuavaTypeModifier.java:38)
```

The following post was helpful but my issue is with the dependencies.
[How to use swagger with dropwizard .0.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301054/how-to-use-swagger-with-dropwizard-0-7-0)

What should my POM contain?  My dropwizard dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank you

Comment: Odd - swagger runs fine with dropwizard 0.7.0 for me. What's the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` for your project? Can you add the complete POM?

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.thoughtworks.paranamer</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need guava library during runtime, so add

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
 <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
 <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: then i just get another error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyDescription
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyDescription(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:492).  I wonder if the other post i linked to actually works or not, and if so how did they resolve the dependencies

Comment: that means this class isn't available, you need to figure out the dependency which contains this class and add it as we did for guava

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to look at miredot. I went down the swagger road, and had a bit of a hard time even if I integrated swagger quite a bit in prior non-DW projects. Then accidentally stumbled across miredot and it just works for us, however the CE edition doesn't have some of the B&W...

Answer (score 0):

For swagger spec 2.0, please see the updated sample here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/develop_2.0/samples/java-dropwizard

It has an updated application class for use with the 1.5.1-M1 swagger-core.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dropwizard-swagger`.

Look at the [Version Matrix](https://github.com/federecio/dropwizard-swagger#version-matrix) in the Swagger's GitHub page. It includes this:

```
dropwizard-swagger  Dropwizard  Swagger API     Swagger UI
----------------------------------------------------------
< 0.5               0.7.x       1.3.2           ?
0.5.x               0.7.x       1.3.12          v2.1.4-M1
0.6.x               0.8.0       1.3.12          v2.1.4-M1
0.7.x               0.8.0       1.5.1-M2        v2.1.4-M1
```

In your case you simply need :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.federecio</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
</dependency>
```