# Programmatically append Swagger operations to generated JSON

Tags: swagger

I have a Dropwizard application with Swagger annotated Java resource classes. I'm also creating [programatic REST resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html) which, of course, don't end up in the generated Swagger JSON. Is it possible to programmatically add operations via the Java Swagger API such that they end up in the generated JSON along with the annotated resources?

I tried using `DefaultJaxrsApiReader.appendOperation` but it had no effect.

I'm using `com.wordnik:swagger-jaxrs_2.10:1.3.12`

**EDIT**

I ended up just writing a Servlet filter to update the Swagger JSON response. It would be great to get @fehguy's suggestions working somehow. I think that `swagger-jaxrs_2.10:1.3.12` isn't new enough to support those POJOs.

Answer (score 2):

as of swagger-core-1.5.1-M1, you can build a swagger POJO which simply needs to be returned by your web application.  That means, you can programmatically create the Swagger object and serve it up as JSON from your web service.

For examples of how to build a swagger pojo you can [look at the source](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/develop_2.0/modules/swagger-models/src/main/java/com/wordnik/swagger/models/Swagger.java) or an example (test) of [building one](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/develop_2.0/modules/swagger-core/src/test/scala/SwaggerSerializerTest.scala).

You can also mutate the generated swagger object in your application.  That means you can dynamically generate / modify swagger at runtime.  There is an example in the swagger-codegen project, where the online code generator (swagger-generator) will detect what languages are enabled in the code generation logic via SPI, and update the swagger spec accordingly with the options:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-generator/src/main/java/com/wordnik/swagger/generator/DynamicSwaggerConfig.java

Comment: I like option to mutate the swagger object. I'm configuring the Dropwizard / JAX-RS integration like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301054/how-to-use-swagger-with-dropwizard-0-7-0 How can I get at the swagger object from any of those objects? Or is there some static way to access it?